# Models won't load from store

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

For the application I am developing Ember.js + Ember Data seems like a good solution. However I can not even get a simple version using both libraries to work. The problem is that the data provided by my JSON file is not correctly loaded or shown.

My app.js looks like. I run all libraries on the edge.

```
var App = Em.Application.create({});

App.store = DS.Store.create({
    revision: 6,
    adapter: DS.RESTAdapter.create({
        bulkCommit: false
    })
});

App.Item = DS.Model.extend({
    pluginName: DS.attr('string')
});

App.regionController = Em.ArrayController.create({
    content: App.store.findAll(App.Item)
});
```

I have one template that looks like:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
    <ul>
    {{#each regionController}}
        <li>{{item}}</li>
    {{/each}}
    </ul>
</script>
```

The request to the json file is made correctly (I see the request pop up in Firebug) and has the following contents:

```
{
    items: [{
        "id": "3",
        "pluginName": "text"
    },
    {
        "id": "3",
        "pluginName": "split"
    }]
}
```

Can anyone spot what I am doing wrong?

Comment: How does it run if you switch over to the fixture adapter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your template should probably look like this:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
    <ul>
      {{#each item in regionController}}
        <li>{{item.pluginName}}</li>
      {{/each}}
    </ul>
</script>
```

Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: Just an addition: When using the router in Ember, the current controller will be injected with the controller responsible for that outlet via `connectOutlet`, so the template should look the same except for `{{#each item in controller}}` instead of `{{#each item in regionController}}`. If not using the router, the template should look like Zack's

Comment: unfortunately changing the view in that way does not work. Still the list remains empty.

Comment: @RoelvanDuijnhoven you should make a fiddle to see what's going on

Comment: Capturing the actual ajax request within JsFiddle is not that trivial. But the above code without this request can be found at: http://jsfiddle.net/tGNXy/2/

I have again put several hours into fixing this problem today, but I can not seem to get this working. Frustrating!

Comment: @RoelvanDuijnhoven you should use a Router. Here is a working example using Ember.Router: http://jsfiddle.net/ppanagi/6jX2j/   . Go here to see the result: http://jsfiddle.net/ppanagi/6jX2j/show

Comment: Your Fiddle works fine, the models show correctly. However, when I replace the FixtureAdapter by the original RestAdapter the models disappear. Is my JSON perhaps incorrectly formatted, or what else can be wrong?